# Ошибка в фукнции asung js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list, такая вылазит ошибка если добавить в коносле лог await

```
function jax(s) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
    url: '/test.php',
    success: function(data){ 
        resolve(s)
    }
});

});

}



async function asyncCall() {
    var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "cherry"];
    fruits.forEach((element, index) => {
        console.log( await jax(index) ); //Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    });
}


asyncCall();
```

Comment: `await` можно использовать только в `async` функции. Напишите `fruits.forEach(async (element, index)`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, но так он не дожидается когда jax даст ответ шлет сразу всё

Comment: Да, все верно, так и будет работать :) Что бы дожидаться предыдущего ответа - используйте цикл `for(var i=0...`